# Problems when running on ClearOS7/Centos7

Tags: stellar-core, postgres

In order to get stellar-core running on ClearOS7 (binary compatible with Centos7), I have had to use postgresql from one of the SCLo repos (Special interest groups) as the normal Centos version of postgresql is 9.2 and stellar-core requires >= 9.5. I also had to use the SCLo llvm-toolset-7.

Having installed rh-postgresql12, I can compile with:

```
export libpq_CFLAGS=/opt/rh/rh-postgresql12/root/usr/lib64/libpq.so.rh-postgresql12-5
export libpq_LIBS=/opt/rh/rh-postgresql12/root/usr/lib64/libpq.so.rh-postgresql12-5
scl enable llvm-toolset-7 ./autogen.sh
scl enable llvm-toolset-7 ./configure
scl enable rh-postgresql12 'scl enable llvm-toolset-7 make'
```

I am running using an `sqlite3` database. This should OK but now if I try to run anything I have to do commands like `scl enable rh-postgresql12 'stellar-core  --conf /etc/stellar/stellar.cfg new-hist local'` otherwise I get errors like:

```
[root@proxmox107 stellar-core]# /usr/local/bin/stellar-core --conf /etc/stellar/stellar.cfg new-db
/usr/local/bin/stellar-core: error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.rh-postgresql12-5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Why is it even trying to use `libpq.so.rh-postgresql12-5` when I am using an sqlite3 database?

I can get round the issue either by prefixing every command with `scl enable rh-postgresql12` or by compiling with the stock postgresql (9.2) installed at the same time and changing the export lines to:

```
export libpq_CFLAGS=/usr/lib64/libpq.so
export libpq_LIBS=/usr/lib64/libpq.so
```

But this seems odd to require both postgresql-9.2 and postgresql-12 just for this.

I you would like to leave support for postgresql compiled into stellar-core so I could revert to it if I wanted to, but if I can't, how do I compile removing postgresql support completely?